# NullReferenceException not caught for 1.1 Framework program in Windows 10 Creator

Tags: c#, windows-10, .net-1.1

I was wondering if anyone who has Dotnet Framework 1.1 installed on a machine with Windows 10 Creator can run a little test for me.

It would appear that the following snippet of code (incorrectly) produces a StackOverflow exception and crashes.

```
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Test.Run(null);
    }

    int value = 0;

    public static void Run(Test test)
    { 
        try
        {               
            int i = test.value;
        }
        catch (System.NullReferenceException)
        {                   
        }
    }       
}
```

You don't need Visual Studio installed and the easiest way to compile is to save it to a file (eg Test.cs) and then compile via the command line

```
 %Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\csc.exe Test.cs
```

and then run the resulting Test.exe and see if it crashes.

I know 1.1 isn't supported, but I'm trying to track down crashes in a legacy app which was working fine in a previous build of Windows 10, but has started crashing since the update to Creator. I want to make sure this isn't just a corrupted installation of the 1.1 framework and it's hard to find Windows 10 machines with framework 1.1 installed.

Comment: Your title says it is a NullRefrenceException but the question says StackOverflowException. Which is it?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The code should produce a NullReferenceException which should be caught, but it throws a StackOverFlowException instead.

Comment: [.net 1.1 is no longer supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925570(v=vs.110).aspx) since Windows 7, so no wonder that someday it causes issues. why not target a higher .net runtime?

Comment: @yoger: Can you please help me how to install .NET 1.1 for Windows 10 OS. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I compiled and ran it just as specified, but cannot reproduce any unhandled `NullReferenceException` scenario. Have you tried debugging your code?

Compiler info:

> Microsoft (R) Visual C# .NET Compiler version 7.10.6001.4
>   for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework version 1.1.4322

The code I compiled:

```
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Test.Run(null);
        Test.Run(new Test());
    }

    int value = 1;

    public static void Run(Test test)
    {
        try
        {
            int i = test.value;
            System.Console.WriteLine("The value is:" + i);
        }
        catch (System.NullReferenceException e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message + "was handled.");
        }
    }
}
```

And the output:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.was handled.
>
> The value is:1

Comment: That crashes for me on the int i=test.value line. What build of windows are you running? Mine is Version 1703 (OS Build 15063.296)

Comment: Im on 1607 (build 14393.1198).

Comment: That's the old (Anniversary Update) build.It only goes wrong on the new (Creator) build.

Comment: I'll do some updating, retest this scenario and get back to you :)

Comment: Well there's definitely something wrong. Updated windows to your version and got : 
`Unhandled exception at 0x79243841 (mscorwks.dll) in Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000B0.`
`[Resource lookup failed - infinite recursion detected.  Resource name: Arg_NullReferenceException]`